# How do i get text from shadow root when e2e testing with codecept-puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, e2e-testing, shadow-dom, codeceptjs

This is my HTML Structure
[image: HTML Structure]

I want to make sure that the title is 'Favorite Restaurant', How do i test this using codecept-puppeteer ?

I already tried this, but it doesn't work

```
Feature('Favorite Restaurant');

Before(({ I }) => {
  I.amOnPage('/#/favorite');
});

Scenario('showing empty favorite restaurants', async ({ I }) => {
  I.wait(3);
  const text = await I.grabTextFrom(
    'pierce/favorite-module .section-header h2',
  );
  console.log(text);
});
```

[image: Test log]